# Java Twitter4j addListener not defined for type twitterStream

Tags: java, twitter4j

```
package beproject1;
import twitter4j.FilterQuery;
import twitter4j.Status;
import twitter4j.StatusDeletionNotice;
import twitter4j.StatusListener;
import twitter4j.TwitterStream;
import twitter4j.TwitterStreamFactory;
import twitter4j.User;
import twitter4j.conf.ConfigurationBuilder;


public class Twitter {

        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();
            cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
            .setOAuthConsumerKey("ab")
            .setOAuthConsumerSecret("cd")
            .setOAuthAccessToken("ef")
            .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("gh")
            ;

            TwitterStream twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(cb.build()).getInstance();

            StatusListener listener = new StatusListener() {

                @Override
                public void onException(Exception arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onDeletionNotice(StatusDeletionNotice arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                public void onScrubGeo(long arg0, long arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

                @Override
                public void onStatus(Status status) {
                    User user = status.getUser();

                    // gets Username
                    String username = status.getUser().getScreenName();
                    System.out.println(username);
                    String profileLocation = user.getLocation();
                    System.out.println(profileLocation);
                    long tweetId = status.getId(); 
                    System.out.println(tweetId);
                    String content = status.getText();
                    System.out.println(content +"\n");

                }

                @Override
                public void onTrackLimitationNotice(int arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            };
            FilterQuery fq = new FilterQuery();

            String keywords[] = {"ireland"};

            fq.track(keywords);

            twitterStream.addListener(listener); // this line errors out
            twitterStream.filter(fq);  

        }
    }
```

The line with statement `twitterStream.addListener(listener)` shows error.
    It says `addListener` not defined for the type `twitterStream`.
    Can anyone tell me why?
I have tried including other `twitter4j` jars but the problem persists for all of them.

Comment: The last line in the code is not actually a part of the code. I wrote it to show that it is the line which is showing error.

Comment: What is the error you are seeing? Adding it here will help others assist.

Answer (score 1):

This is the correct way of using Twitter4J to capture tweets in stream:

```
    // Prepare configuration.
    ConfigurationBuilder configurationBuilder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerKey(Config.TwitterConsumerKey);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(Config.TwitterConsumerSecret);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessToken(Config.OAuthAccessToken);
    configurationBuilder.setOAuthAccessTokenSecret(Config.OAuthAccessTokenSecret);

    // Create the Twitter stream object.
    twitterStream = new TwitterStreamFactory(configurationBuilder.build()).getInstance();
    twitterStream.addListener(new StreamListener());

    // Crawl.
    FilterQuery filterQuery = new FilterQuery();
    filterQuery.follow([your_set_of_user_IDs]);
    filterQuery.track([your_set_of_keywords]);

    twitterStream.filter(filterQuery);
```

Notice that `StreamListener` is a concrete class implementing the `StatusListener` interface, in which you define what to do when a tweet is captured.